# Copy the values of Column F that are greater than 0 to Column C

Tags: excel, vba

I copy **values** of Column F **(F7:F30)** to Column C **(C7:C30)**.

I need to only copy values that are **greater than 0**.

```vb
Range("F7:F30").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("C7").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
  :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try.

```
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("F7:F30")
        If VBA.IsNumeric(c.Value) And c.Value > 0 Then
            Cells(c.Row, "C").Value = c.Value
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your code worked perfectly the way I needed

Answer (score 1):

One could remove the 0 after copying like that

```
Sub removeZero()

    Dim rg1 As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rg1 = ws.Range("F7:F30")

    Dim rg2 As Range
    Set rg2 = ws.Range("C7:C30")

    rg1.Copy
    rg2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    ' Remove
    rg2.Replace "0", vbNullChar, xlWhole

End Sub
```

**Update**: The code above only replaces Zeros, it will not replace values less than 0. One would need this code for that

```
Sub removeLEZero()

    Dim rg1 As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rg1 = ws.Range("F7:F30")

    Dim rg2 As Range
    Set rg2 = ws.Range("C7:C30")

    rg1.Copy
    rg2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    rg2.Name = "a"
    ' Uncomment the folliwng line if you would like to only copy numbers
    ' Range("a") = Evaluate("IF(ISNUMBER(a),a,"""")")
    Range("a") = Evaluate("IF(a<=0,"""",a)")
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried yours, and at the moment Taller's solution works as I needed, but yours could be used in other sheets I have. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's how with an array (this does erase the existing C-value if there was any, if you don't want that, use Taller's solution):

```
Sub test()
    Dim arr, cRange As Range, dRange As Range, i As Long
    Set cRange = Range("F7:F30")
    Set dRange = Range("C7")
    arr = cRange.Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        If Not (IsNumeric(arr(i, 1)) And arr(i, 1) > 0) Then arr(i, 1) = ""
    Next i
    dRange.Resize(UBound(arr, 1)).Value = arr
End Sub
```

If anything's unclear, let me know.

Comment: Thank you, but removing values in C will cause a massive problem for me for the current sheet; your code could be used in other sheets I have, just like Storax codes.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad you had variety in answers to get the right one from.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one if you don't want holes where the negative numbers used to be:

```
Sub test()
    Dim arr, arr2, i#, j#
    arr = Range("F7:F30")
    ReDim arr2(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1)
    j# = 1
    For i# = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i, 1) > 0 Then arr2(j, 1) = arr(i, 1): j = j + 1
    Next
    Range("C7").Resize(j).Value = arr2
End Sub
```

Comment: Thankfully, I do not have negative values in F, but I tested yours, and it changes the entire C value, so it was not the intended solution for my current sheet, but I want to thank you for the input